# A free chain complex is acyclic if and only if it is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

The proof of this lemma in Spanier's *Alegraic topology* doesn't make any sense to me.

$s_n: Z_{n} \rightarrow C_{n+1}$ as the right inverse of the boundary map restricted to the image, but then he defines

$D_n = s_n(\mathbb 1_{C_n} - s_{n-1}\partial_n): C_n\rightarrow C_{n+1} $

Which suggest that the $s_n$ is $C_n\rightarrow C_{n+1}$. I suppose that there should be some inclusions along the way, but since I cannot really see what's the idea behind this proof I don't want to mess that up

Answer (score 2):

In between the two statements you quoted, Spanier notes that $1_{C_q} - s_{q-1}\partial_q$ maps $C_q$ to $Z_q(C)$. If we accept this, then we will be free to compose $s_q$ with $1_{C_q} - s_{q-1}\partial_q$, because the latter maps into the domain of $s_q$. To see why this statement about the range of $1_{C_q} - s_{q-1}\partial_q$ is true, we refer to the fact that $s_{q-1}$ is a right inverse of $\partial_q$, so $\partial_q(1_{C_q} - s_{q-1}\partial_q) = \partial_q - (\partial_q s_{q-1})\partial_q = \partial_q - \partial_q = 0$, which establishes that $1_{C_q} - s_{q-1}\partial_q$ maps into the kernel of $\partial_q$, i.e. $Z_q(C)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the missing piece